# Escaping the Underscore Character to Avoid Unwanted Italics

Tags: bug, status-completed, markdown, character-escaping

I was just answering a question on SOF where I typed App_Code blah blah blah App_Code into the answer. Markdown interpreted the two underscores as beginning and ending some italicized text, and thus in the preview, it appeared like this: App*Code blah blah blah App*Code.

Is there some way to avoid this? Maybe a way to escape special markdown characters in cases like this? (I had to resort to using the &#95; html entity to get my question to appear properly, but that is kind of annoying)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that the real-time preview will incorrectly italicize, but the actual post will not.

Example:

... I typed App_Code blah blah blah App_Code ...

edit: the real-time preview was updated to correctly show how we block intra-word emphasis.

Comment: Having the preview and the post differ is a source of numerous confused complaints. What are the chances of getting them to match consistently?

Comment: @dlamblin: this has become a pet peeve of mine (since it's a serious problem on my Stack Exchange site), so I've been tweaking wmd.js to make the preview match the post (see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1227#30869). My current version handles italics and bold almost exactly like the server side implementation, but it's not quite perfect, and it's non-trivial to figure out what rules are being applied on the server. If you want to help figure out the rules, you can experiment on this SE site without bothering anybody: http://faketestsite.stackexchange.com/questions/4